# freemarker if statement sequencing

Tags: logic, freemarker, responsys

I'm trying to write an `#if` statement with a sequence of numbers. Basically, if a certain field matches any of a subset of numbers (shown below with `||` or operators) then assign it as "bayarea", `elseif` a different subset, then a different name, etc. Is this possible without a bunch of nested "or" statements?

I'm getting a syntax error saying that it's expecting a boolean yes/no statement.

```
<#if TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE == 
{12||21||22||38||46||67||71||74||76||77||83||86||104||113||119||143>
{bayarea}
 <#elseif TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE == 
{34||62||84||91||137||144||152||169}>
{blueridge}
<#elseif TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE == 
{18||44||49||50||61||68||121||182}>
 {frontrange}
<#else>
</#if>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nesting:

```
<#if TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE == 12
     || TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE == 21 || ...>
```

Though that's surely too verbose, but you can do this:

```
<#assign store = TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE>
<#if store == 12 || store == 21 || ...>
```

But I think what you are looking for is this (or this combined with the `#assign`, if you have several `#elseif`-s):

```
<#if [12, 21, ...]?seq_contains(TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE)>
```

This is a possibility too (just don't forget the `#break`-s):

```
<#switch TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE>
   <#case 12><#case 21>...
     {bayarea}
     <#break>
   <#case 34><#case 62>...
     {bluebridge}
     <#break>
   ...
</#switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are four good answers above.  To expand on it, I'd do something like this:

```
<#assign pref_store = TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE>

<#assign area = "">

<#assign group1 = [12,21,22,38,46,67,71,74,76,77,83,86,104,113,119,143]>

<#assign group2 = [34,62,84,91,137,144,152,169]>

<#assign group3 = [18,44,49,50,61,68,121,182]>

<#if group1?seq_contains(pref_store)>

    <#assign area = "bayarea">

<#elseif group2?seq_contains(pref_store)>

    <#assign area = "blueridge">

<#elseif group3?seq_contains(pref_store)>

    <#assign area = "frontrange">

<#else>

    <#assign area = "whatever">

</#if>
```

Your Preferred Store Area is `${area}`.

---

Alternatively, instead of Sequences / Arrays, you could also set these values as a string.

For example:

```
<#assign pref_store = "${TEST_CONTACTS_LIST.PREFERRED_STORE}">

<#assign group1 = "12,21,22,38,46,67,71,74,76,77,83,86,104,113,119,143">
```

then the if statement would be the following:

```
<#if group1?contains(pref_store)>
```

(Notice the `?contains` instead of `?seq_contains`)

etc..